# How to give the multipart file input in junit

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am using JUnit for testing of Daoimpl. In one of the cases, I need to give an input which is a multipart file. I searched the internet and found that mockmultipartfile is used, but didn't find any example. Please provide me one for better understanding.

I am using **spring** and **JUnit 4.11**

Answer (score 10):

I have done the multipart file as a input for junit by using [[MockMultipartFile]](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockMultipartFile.html).

```
FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream( "path of the file");  
MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "NameOfTheFile", "multipart/form-data", inputFile);
```

now use the file input as multipart file.

Answer (score 0):

In case of unit test using Mockito, hence only for mocking parameter i added as following no need if file just to mock

```
MockMultipartFile kmlfile = new MockMultipartFile("data", "filename.kml", "text/plain", "some kml".getBytes());
```

Above code helped in creating mock file just for mocking

Following is the Controller service which am mocking

```
@RestController
public class LayerDataController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/saveOnflyMaplayerdata", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Map<String, Object> saveOnflyMaplayerdata(
            @RequestParam("name") String name, 
            @RequestParam("fileData") MultipartFile fileData) {
        try {
            boolean isValidFile = false;
            if (!fileData.isEmpty()) {

                String fileName = fileData.getOriginalFilename();
                LOGGER.info("fileName : " + fileName);
                String filetype = FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
                LOGGER.info("fileName : " + filetype);

                switch (filetype) {

                case "csv":
                    isValidFile = true;
                    break;

                case "kml":
                    isValidFile = true;
                    break;

                case "kmz":
                    isValidFile = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    isValidFile = false;
                    break;
                }

                if (isValidFile) {
                    //call save method
                } else {
                    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
                    response.put("status", false);
                    response.put("err_msg", "Unexpected Filetype/extection failed uploading");
                    return response;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Testcase written using Mockito (Mocking multipart file)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import com.example.service.OnflyFileSave;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LayerDataControllerTest  {

    @Mock
    OnflyFileSave onfly;
    
    @InjectMocks
    LayerDataController testclass;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }

    @Test
    public void testSaveOnflyMaplayerdataCsv() {
    //no file is path is used as simpley mocking is done just to Mock in method level
        MockMultipartFile csvfile = new MockMultipartFile("data", "filename.csv", "text/plain", "some csv".getBytes());
        testclass.saveOnflyMaplayerdata("name", csvfile);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSaveOnflyMaplayerdataKml() {
        MockMultipartFile kmlfile = new MockMultipartFile("data", "filename.kml", "text/plain", "some kml".getBytes());
        testclass.saveOnflyMaplayerdata("name", kmlfile);
    }
}
```

Package used as following in spring boot

```
<!-- For Mockito Spring boot -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency> 
<!-- For Mockito Spring boot -->

<!-- For Mock multipart -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- For Mock multipart -->
```